# What old LCD monitor am I thinking about?

Tags: ibm-pc, lcd-display, identify-this-peripheral

I once had a PC with an LCD monitor and I'd like to remember what model that monitor was. Here's what I remember:

- It was basically a beige rectangular box with right angles on all corners. Only the bottom edge was like a cylinder that allowed to tilt the screen up and down. The screen itself was maybe 6" in size.
- It was black and white (or rather the usual monochrome LCD colors).
- I have only ever seen text on it, I don't know if it had a graphics mode.
- It didn't use a 15-pin Sub-D VGA connector. I think it used a 9-pin Sub-D like a modem. I don't remember the gender though.
- Therefore it needed a special graphics card (not PCI, maybe ISA), but I don't know if that card was specific to the monitor or just an older generic graphics card.
- The PC was x86 architecture, probably 386 or newer, but that doesn't mean they were sold together.
- It was used in Germany some time between 1980 and 2005.

[image: Drawing]

Comment: Mind to add country and time - maybe as well where the PC was used (school, home, business).

Comment: 9-pin suggests it's a TTL monitor, Hercules or CGA-compatible.

Comment: @Raffzahn Country is Germany. The machine was one of many that somehow ended up in my basement, that puts time at anything between 1980 and 2005.

Comment: @AndreKR Please add this and whatever else there is to the question text. Also, was ist scrapped when it ended up in you hands? Where did it come from? What was it originally used for? When did it arrive? What was the machine like? Add whatever may help to pin down the circumstances. After all, squarish B&W on a tiltable stand isn't exactly a rare feature for LCD :))  (We can at least be sure that 1980 is rather early for an LCD even more so for something PC compatible :))

Comment: @Raffzahn Edited. I don't remember at all where it came from, probably from some garage I cleared out. The machine itself was unremarkable, they were all pretty much the same size, weren't they? I think it was one that was laying flat, but might also be one of the first small towers. I'm not actually sure I even had the machine that originally came with the screen.

Comment: @Raffzahn About your last sentence... I ran same Google images searches ("old lcd screen" etc.) and surprisingly I didn't find *any* squarish B&W LCD screens on a tiltable stand.

Comment: So it turns out they do (or did) make modern LCD monitors with 9-pin plugs for older systems. And while they are color monitors, if they receive a monochrome signal, they might display it in black and white and so you might think it's a monochrome monitor when it's not. http://www.ramplus.com/ltmi12lcdmo9.html

Comment: @snips-n-snails The panel itself had the look of those old laptop LCDs with the contrast slider. I don't remember it actually having a contrast adjustment but maybe it did. I'd be surprised if it wasn't a B&W screen. Also the shape was quite different from modern monitors, it looked something like [this](https://i.imgur.com/d7vkUwj.png).

Comment: "Only the bottom edge was like a cylinder that allowed to tilt the screen up and down." - can you be more specific here? Do mean that you could rotate the screen so the top edge moved closer or further? Or did is have a sliding effect so you could raise or lower the entire device over the desk. My monitor has both...

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Check out my drawing in the comment before yours, does that clear things up?

Comment: The monitor in the drawing looks like it's about to topple backwards. And it looks awkward to adjust the angle, you would have to hold down the base with one hand while you tilt the display with the other.

Comment: @snips-n-snails Both points did apply to the actual screen. :) It didn't help that it was rather lightweight and its cable rather heavy.

Comment: Given the 6 inch estimated diagonal dimension and the 9 pin connector, I'm willing to bet this was an industrial control panel that got repurposed for a PC.  Do you recall if there were any mounting holes on the base?

Comment: @BrandonXavier Pretty sure there weren't any. I have to disagree with your guess, the flimsy plastic case, the screen itself, the foldable feet, it didn't look like an industrial control panel at all.

Comment: Would this be similar to what you remember? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pJvqnpMT8RM

Comment: @thkala This is definitely not the model I mean but the form factor and the reaction time of the LCD is indeed quite similar.